# Запятая между месяцем и годом

Tags: запятая

Нужно ли ставить запятую между месяцем и годом, когда речь идет о номере журнала. К примеру, в тексте цитата из журнала "Коммерсанта" от марта 1999 года.

"...здесь какая-то цитата",

"Коммерсант", март(,) 1999

Если в таком написании, нужно ли после слова "март" ставить запятую?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможные варианты:

"Коммерсант", март, 1999-й.

"Коммерсант", март 1999-го.

"Коммерсант", март 1999 г. (если прочитать как "девятого").

"Коммерсант", март, 1999 г. (если прочитать как "девятый").

Хотя на практике обычно ни г., ни буквенное наращение не используют. Пишут: март, 1999; март 1999; 03/1999. Это не соответствует правилам, но такова распространенная практика.

Мне больше нравится март 1999 г.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, здесь запятая не нужна. Сравните: "улица города Москвы". Тут ведь запятая тоже не ставится. Так и тут: "март такого-то года".
Единственная ситуация, когда запятая нужна, это - "март, 1999 год". Тут идет перечисление обстоятельств действия (лингвисты, поправьте, если ошибаюсь). То есть, как бы две равнозначные и самостоятельные координаты времени в именительном падеже.